# Making two COL Bootstrap 3 same height, but with padding

Tags: html, css, height, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-tables

I want to make to look like this, buit with no javascript, here is screenshot that i want to look like

[image]

This is what i have made for now in boostrap 3, css in in inline because i use less, and this is easy way :)

HTML

```
 <section class="container-fluid" style="background-color:Red;
  background-size: cover; padding-top:145px; padding-bottom:145px;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="element" style="background-color:white;  opacity:.90;
  -moz-opacity:.90; 
  filter:alpha(opacity=90); padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:44px; margin-right:15px; padding-left:15px;">
              <h2  class="color-brand">HEADING 2</h2>
              <p class="color-grey">Hello Mate</p>
            </div>
            </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="element" style="background-color:white;  opacity:.90;
  -moz-opacity:.90; 
  filter:alpha(opacity=90); padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:44px; margin-right:15px; padding-left:15px;">
              <h2  class="color-brand">HEADING 2</h2>
              <p class="color-grey">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</section>
```

And this is working jfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/D9tc4/

Comment: May want to check out this Q&A. --- [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative margin like this..

```
.element{
    padding:20px;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/125300